# XPath: Match whole word (using matches function with case insensitive flag)

Tags: regex, search, xpath, xpath-2.0

Using XPath, I would like to "Match whole word" (option for user, just like in VS search).

It seems as though the functions `contains` and `matches` work similarly though matches allows for flags like `i` for case insensitivity.

In other words, I am getting the same results with these two XPath queries:

```
<pets>
    <dog name="Rupert" color="grey"/>
    <dog name="Ralph" color="brown"/>
    <cat name="Marvin the Cat" color="white"/>
    <cat name="Garfield the Cat" color="orange"/>
    <cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
    <cat name="Fluffy" color="black"/>
</pets>

Matches XPath: //cat[descendant-or-self::*[@*[matches(.,'Cat')]]]
    returns:
    <cat name="Marvin the Cat" color="white"/>
    <cat name="Garfield the Cat" color="orange"/>
    <cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>


Contains XPath: //cat[descendant-or-self::*[@*[contains(.,'Cat')]]]
    returns:
    <cat name="Marvin the Cat" color="white"/>
    <cat name="Garfield the Cat" color="orange"/>
    <cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
```

But I would like to use `matches` to return results that match "Cat" whole word only:

```
<cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
```

How can I adjust the matches query so it matches whole word?

**EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I need to still use the matches function because I need the case insensitivity flag.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using `^` and `$` characters as anchors?

```
//cat[descendant-or-self::*[@*[matches(.,'^Cat$')]]]
```

From [RegEx Syntax in XQuery 1.0 and XPath 2.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#regex-syntax):

> Two meta-characters, **^** and **$** are added. By default, the meta-character
>   **^** matches the start of the entire string, while **$** matches the end of
>   the entire string.

Comment: Hmm.. this gives me the result I want. But could you explain the ^$ anchors? I've never used them before..

Comment: Added a link into an answer, see the "Two meta-characters..." section.

Comment: Thanks, I will still need to do some testing, but this seems to do the trick!

Comment: `^` and `$` match start/end of the line, not start/end of substrings with word boundary

Answer (score 4):

There are three functions/operators of relevance here.

matches() does a regular expression match; you can use it to match a substring or to match the entire string by use of anchors (^cat$), and you can set the 'i' flag to make it case-blind.

contains() does an exact match of a substring; you can use the third argument (collation) to request a case-blind match, but the way in which collations are specified depends on the processor you are using.

The eq operator does an exact match of the entire string; the "default collation" (which in the case of XPath will typically be set using the processor's API) can be used to request case-blind matching. This seems to be the one that is closest to your requirement, the only drawback is that specifying the collation is more system-dependent than using the "i" flag with matches().

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
//cat[@*='Cat']
```

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I still want to use the matches function because I need case insensitivity... (see edit above).

Answer (score 2):

> But I would like to use matches to return results that match "Cat"
>   whole word only:
>
> ```
> <cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
> ```

**There are different XPath expression that select the wanted element**:

Use:

```
/*/cat[matches(@name, '^cat$', 'i')]
```

Or use:

```
/*/cat[lower-case(@name) eq 'cat']
```

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/*/cat[matches(@name, '^cat$', 'i')]"/>
======
  <xsl:copy-of select=
   "/*/cat[lower-case(@name) eq 'cat']"/>

 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<pets>
    <dog name="Rupert" color="grey"/>
    <dog name="Ralph" color="brown"/>
    <cat name="Marvin the Cat" color="white"/>
    <cat name="Garfield the Cat" color="orange"/>
    <cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
    <cat name="Fluffy" color="black"/>
</pets>
```

**this transformation evaluates the two XPath expressions and copies the selected elements to the output**:

```
  <cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
======
  <cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
//cat[@*='Cat']
```

results in:

```
<cat name="Cat" color="grey"/>
```

I verified using [Xacobeo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/xacobeo).

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for. I still want to use the matches function because I need case insensitivity... (see edit above).

Comment: @developer Try this: 

`//cat[translate(@*,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='cat']`

This assumes you always pass the string you want to match by as lowercase.