# Xpath does not recognize regex parts

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath

I am new to this and I am trying to understand the usage of selenium and XPath

```
string exp = "//*[@id=\"g_1_bHwVovAN\"]/td[2]";
var dateTime = chromeDriver.FindElementsByXPath(exp);
```

With this code, I can only take 1 element. How can I change this "bHwVovAN" part, so I can reach the all that kinds of elements on the website.

```
string exp = "//*[@id=\"g_1_[^[0-9+]]\"]/td[2]";
var dateTime = chromeDriver.FindElementsByXPath(exp);
```

I tried to use regex, but It did not work. It did not recognize regex parts. Also, I looked at the other posts, and tried to use matches, and also did not work. How can I solve it?

If I did not write clear and correct way, I am also new to English. Sorry

Comment: To use regex, don't you need to use `fn:matches`? Otherwise, is is doing an equality match, and: *that won't match via equality*. Like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10404321/23354. As a complete guess, maybe: `string exp = "//*[matches(@id, 'g_1_[^[0-9+]]')]/td[2]";` ?

Comment: @MarcGravell i tried to use that template but it did not work [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21405267/xpath-using-regex-in-contains-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `matches()` function in `XPath 2.0` that would solve your issue, but `selenium` doesn't support this `XPath` version.

You can try below to match elements with `id` attribute that starts with `"g_1_"`:

```
string exp = "//*[starts-with(@id,\"g_1_\")]/td[2]";
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works perfectly.